Physical meaning of the CG coefficient $\langle j_1 m_1 j_2 m_2 |00 \rangle $
This particular CG coefficient has the value
$$ \langle j_1 m_1 j_2  m_2 |00 \rangle = \delta_{j_1 j_2 }\delta_{m_1,-m_2} \frac{(-1)^{j_1  - m_1 }}{\sqrt{2j_1 + 1 }}. $$
The interesting point is that its magnitude is a constant independent of $m_1$.
Is there any argument for this simple fact?

Is that supposed to read $(-1)^{j_1-m_1}$?

@Triatticus   Thank you for this typo.

I guess it is like this. $|00\rangle $ is a $s$-state, it is rotatioanlly invariant, so the weight of $|j_1 m_1 \rangle $ should be independent of $m_1 $.

Right.  As indicated, 00 drops out! It’s hardly there!

$$ \langle j_1~ m_1 ~~j_2 ~ m_2 |00 \rangle = (-)^{j_1-m_1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2j_2+1}} \langle j_1 m_1 ~00|j_2~  -\!m_2  \rangle \\
= (-)^{j_i-m_1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2j_2+1}} \langle j_1 m_1|j_2~  -\!m_2  \rangle 
=
\delta_{j_1 j_2 }\delta_{m_1,-m_2} \frac{(-1)^{j_1  - m_1 }}{\sqrt{2j_1 + 1 }}. $$
Traceable to the symmetries of the 3-j symbol. What physical meaning  would you expect for a state transitioning to its very self?
